# Rack::Builder 'to_app' method comprehension

Tags: ruby, rack

I saw the Railscast #151. In this video, a Rack's snippet is presented. It corresponds to the `Rack::Builder` module. I'm missing something in the `to_app` method:

```rb
 def to_app
  app = @map ? generate_map(@run, @map) : @run
  fail "missing run or map statement" unless app
  @use.reverse.inject(app) { |a,e| e[a] }
end
```

Could someone explain the last line of the method and what it actually does? I know that `inject` uses an accumulator variable and an element variable. But I don't understand why we could do an array subscription with `e[a]`.

Comment: before explanation you need to provide the body of `generate_map` and the type of instance variables like `@use`,`@run` and `@map`. Please provide these informations

Comment: The question is about source code from Rack. It's open source, so one can easily look up the source to see where `@use` comes from (which I did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `[]` is not array access. It's one way to call a lambda or proc, equivalent to `e.call(a)`. (See the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D).) If you look at the [`use` method](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/builder.rb#L81-L87), the `@use` variable is an array of lambdas. This code is running through each middleware (and/or mapping) in reverse order, and calling each lambda with the app as the argument. This is how they build the app bit by bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot :) I realized that I'm still a Ruby noob !

Comment: You're welcome! This code is actually very confusing to read and not well documented. Welcome to open source. :)